Google analytics exporting numbers
I am exporting a report from Google analytics. The numbers for example for users
is shown as 10,907,302 in the report and when I do an export to a csv file it is shown
as "10,907,302". I did not expect the commas to be exported as well. Yes, I know I can
do a query replace in the csv file but there are other columns there that contains strings
with comma in them. Is there a way to export the data without the comma delimter per 1000
for the numbers fields?

Please edit your question and include your code.  You should be able to parse it when it returns from the api and write it to your csv there

Thank you for your reply. I am doing a manual export by pressing the export button in Google analytics. I don't think there is an API I can connect to since this is the old version and not Google analytics 4.

Thank you for the answers. I found out that in Bigquery I could define this field as an INTEGER with the json format for the table and then the comma in the number was removed.

You can export data as TSV (Tab-separated values) in this way the different information is separated by tabs and the comma within the dimensions remains as such:

